# /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 not found CentOS 7.3

Tags: c++, gcc, centos, centos7

I'm developing an app on Ubuntu 16.04. When I'm trying to deploy it on my Centos 7.3 servers, I'm receiving the following error:

```
/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found
/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found
```

I tried to do as mentioned at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20357035/4193208) but I'm still receiving the same error.

In order to compile my app, I compiled gcc 5.4.0 from source.

When I'm trying to update libstdc++ by `yum install libstdc++.x86_64` it says that `Package libstdc++-4.8.5-11.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version`

Comment: You have to deploy your libstdc++ from gcc 5.4.0 custom dependency too.

Comment: i don't understand this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're deploying on CentOS 7, build on CentOS 7.

Otherwise your runtime dependencies won't match up.

It's [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39001658/560648) to ship your Ubuntu's libc and libstdc++ with your application, but you should avoid having to do this, if possible.

Comment: I forgot to mention it, I'm compiling the source code again on my server.

Comment: Where does Ubuntu come into it then?

Comment: The development was done in Ubuntu. After the development done, we build it on CentOS servers.

Comment: Then for the purpose of this question, the development was done on CentOS. It doesn't matter whether your programming/text editor lives on Ubuntu, Windows, Mac or a paper notepad. To me it sounds like your problem is building GCC from source, rather than using the package manager to install whatever comes with CentOS 7.3, and then not installing it properly. Why don't you use CentOS 7's built-in compiler? Then when you have built your application, its dependencies will match whatever comes with CentOS 7. Otherwise you're going to have to manually install the different libs.

Comment: When I tried to use the built-in compiler, I got plenty of errors that says that the version of my gcc is too old.

Comment: Are you writing C++14 or something? What new features do you need? Try to avoid that - going off-piste with compilers is not pleasant. (I've done it recently because I needed C++11 on CentOS 6 — you have to bundle the runtimes and play around with linker settings — although you may be able to statically link instead, depending on your requirements, which you haven't stated)

Comment: Well, CentOS 7 comes with GCC 4.8, which supports [most of] C++11. Specifically what was the problem you were having with the built-in compiler? You might be better off trying to resolve _that_.